# How to make my layout fit in all screens

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

I have gone through many relative answers on stockoverflow and link's such as [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) or [Screen Compatibility Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)
I have created the following relative layout and I am trying to make it look alike in all android screens.

My images fit perfect for 4.8 inch phones but when I try to use a 2.8 inch display or something like like that, some buttons go on top of others, and they do not shrink.
Does anyone have any suggestion how to improve that?
And preferably without increasing the size of my app.

Thanks in advance!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:mm="http://millennialmedia.com/android/schema"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Switch_off"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="someMethod"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_off"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/warning_shot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/more"
        android:onClick="someMethod" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBatteryState"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/Switch_off"

        />

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sh"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Switch_off"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/me"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Switch_off"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBatteryInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add a ScrollView to the layout.

Comment: Could you show two pictures: one using a 4.8" screen and one using a 2.8" screen?

Comment: "I have created the following relative layout and I am trying to make it look alike in all android screens" -- that should not be your objective. Your objective should be to have a useful UI for all Android screen sizes. That may require multiple versions of the same layout resource, particularly for handling `-small` screens like a 2.8". This is covered by [the first page that you linked to](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html).

Comment: A [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) will prevent views overlapping in your layout. The issue with supporting multiple screen sizes, and getting the images to look nice however, is the bigger issue and it's covered in the very links you provided. Just keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use **LinearLayout** instead of Relativelayout specially for the issue :

> My images fit perfect for 4.8 inch phones but when I try to use a 2.8
>   inch display or something like like that, some buttons go on top of
>   others, and they do not shrink.

Because When you give **orientation** to Linearlayout then Its child will never get on top of each other for any resolution or screen size.

And If you give them **Weight** then Views will be in fix position for Each and Every device.

For example Put below **Xml** in your project and Check this out in Any resolution, It will give the same Result.

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:mm="http://millennialmedia.com/android/schema"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can share your doubt if you got any.

Comment: Can't make it work in my code :/, even after i add `weight` and `linearlayout`

Comment: can u send all images u have used in above xml? So I can test it.